XGBoost failing with Rabit error on AWS EMR Serverless
I’m using XBoost for regression, specifically the SparkXGBRegressor. I’m able to use it without issues on my local machine. However, I get the following Rabit-related error when executing it on AWS EMR Serverless. Any ideas? Is it related to this?:
2024-05-28 21:54:33.922 [INFO] XGBoost-PySpark: Running xgboost-2.0.3 on 1 workers with
booster params: {‘objective’: ‘reg:squarederror’, ‘device’: ‘cpu’, ‘learning_rate’: 0.03, ‘max_depth’: 5, ‘random_state’: 0, ‘subsample’: 1.0, ‘eval_metric’: ‘rmse’, ‘nthread’: 8}
train_call_kwargs_params: {‘early_stopping_rounds’: 50, ‘verbose_eval’: True, ‘num_boost_round’: 10}
dmatrix_kwargs: {‘nthread’: 8, ‘missing’: 0.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/tmp/spark-86c93d08-da51-4c1d-9834-689be49aad15/train_model.py”, line 436, in
main()
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/my_project/utils/logger_utils.py”, line 38, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py”, line 1157, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py”, line 1078, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py”, line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py”, line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File “/tmp/spark-86c93d08-da51-4c1d-9834-689be49aad15/train_model.py”, line 326, in main
train_model(
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/my_project/utils/logger_utils.py”, line 55, in timed
result: Callable = method(*args, **kw)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/my_project/utils/logger_utils.py”, line 38, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File “/tmp/spark-86c93d08-da51-4c1d-9834-689be49aad15/train_model.py”, line 410, in train_model
model_training_strategy.train_model(
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/my_project/pyspark_utils/model_processor/xgboost_pipeline_model_training_strategy.py”, line 38, in train_model
return model_training_pipeline.fit(my_project_dataframe)
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py”, line 205, in fit
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py”, line 134, in _fit
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py”, line 205, in fit
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/spark/core.py”, line 1136, in _fit
(config, booster) = _run_job()
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/spark/core.py”, line 1122, in _run_job
ret = rdd_with_resource.collect()[0]
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py”, line 1833, in collect
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py”, line 1322, in call
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py”, line 179, in deco
File “/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py”, line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Could not recover from a failed barrier ResultStage. Most recent failure reason: Stage failed because barrier task ResultTask(314, 0) finished unsuccessfully.
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/spark/core.py”, line 1067, in _train_booster
_rabit_args = _get_rabit_args(context, num_workers)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/spark/utils.py”, line 77, in _get_rabit_args
env = _start_tracker(context, n_workers)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/spark/utils.py”, line 66, in _start_tracker
rabit_context = RabitTracker(host_ip=host, n_workers=n_workers)
File “/home/hadoop/environment/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/tracker.py”, line 208, in init
sock.bind((host_ip, port))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address


at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:572)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:86)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:751)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:451)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1962)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:282)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3067)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3003)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3002)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3002)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:2326)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3265)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3205)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3194)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1041)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2406)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2427)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2446)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2471)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Again, it works fine on my computer, so it should be some EMR Serverless configuration issue...
